# Swift 2.2 - Notepad app, Associate a separate textView to a cell without adding ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I am trying to make a notes app, in which different cells in a tableView lead to a different note. They name and add a note and when the cell is clicked, I have a segue to a textView, but when I click on a newly created cell, it leads to the same note. I am wondering the best way to have a different textView for the note when a different cell is clicked. I don't want to have a different ViewController for each note as they can add an infinite number of notes. Please tell me if you need code, because I am not sure which file or files of code you need. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should have one `ListViewController` and one `NoteViewController`. On `prepareForSegue` in the `ListViewController`, you need to pass the information. Something like:

```
let noteVC = segue.destinationViewController as! NoteViewController
noteVC.noteText = selectedText //pass the data for that note
```

In the `NoteViewController`, create a class variable like `var noteText : String?`

Comment: The list is in tableViewController as different cells in the tableView, and the textView is in ViewController, how do I add it in?

Comment: Add what in? `TableViewController` is what I referred to as `ListViewController` above, and `ViewController` is probably `NoteViewController`. The `prepareForSegue` should already be present at the bottom of `TableViewController`, just add the two lines I showed you.

Comment: Do I add the lines in tableViewController or the ViewController?

Comment: You are passing the data from the tableview to the view, correct? So `prepareForSegue` ...which one has the data before you segue? The table.

Comment: Do I make the class variable global or just in the TableViewController? It also shows an error of unresolved identifier at the selected text.

Comment: You need to read up to understand what you're doing. Try this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/113394/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2

Comment: This might be even more applicable to your goal: https://github.com/MakeSchool/iOS8-Notes-Swift

Comment: How do I set it to make it with different text in a different cell everytime it is pressed?

Comment: Since I can't use a different identifier everytime a note is made because they are all coming from the prototype cell, how would I set it to be different?

Comment: Those links I sent you teach you how to do all this. It's not a simple answer for StackOverflow, it's an entire tutorial's worth of information.